# What means warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno when installing from rpmfusion?

Tags: fedora, yum, rpm, gpg, signature

Installing a media player from rpmfusion (via `yum`) yields following output:

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+32 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 21 M
Installed size: 68 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature,
                            key ID 8296fa0f: NOKEY
Public key for a52dec-0.7.4-16.fc17.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/35): a52dec-0.7.4-16.fc17.x86_64.rpm                  |  50 kB
(2/35): faad2-libs-2.7-2.fc17.x86_64.rpm                 | 145 kB
```

What is that supposed to mean?

I've enabled rpmfusion via:

```
 yum localinstall rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

(downloaded the rpm from the rpmfusion site)

I have `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-17-primary` (and symlinks) which has the right key id:

```
# gpg --with-fingerprint RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-17-primary
pub  4096R/8296FA0F  [...]
```

But `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*` does not display an entry for 8296FA0F.

I am not really sure how `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg` and `rpmkeys --import` and friends work together.

And btw, why is `yum` just issuing a warning and not an error that the key is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're not doing anything wrong. The package is incorrectly signed.**

From a thread on lists.rpmfusion.org:

> Are you aware of the other packages that would need to be re-signed,
>   too? a52dec is just *one* example.
>
> Once the changed package arrives at the mirrors, installing it most
>   likely will work fine (requiring a "yum clean packages", however, to
>   purge the package cache).

While this was in reference to the Fedora 16 packages, in all likelihood - your package too suffers from the same fate of a bad signature. Read the rest on [lists.rpmfusion.org](http://lists.rpmfusion.org/pipermail/rpmfusion-developers/2011-November/010667.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link - a [follow-up message](http://lists.rpmfusion.org/pipermail/rpmfusion-developers/2011-November/010672.html) gives me an idea how `yum` is supposed to work when it encounters an unknown key - first it warns with `rpmts_HdrFromFdno ... NOKEY` and after downloading all packages it asks if the missing keys should be imported from `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/...`. I didn't get the 2nd part because the warning freaked me out and I Ctrl+C'd the process before that.